# context.ToListAsync() is not getting any data from the table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The table was created before I created the DBSet for "AssetResource". Since I want to use the EF to make it easier to insert or update, I created the `DbSet<AssetResource>` without calling the add-migration. The table has some data in it already, but when I call using this

```
var list = await context.AssetSources.ToListAsync();
```

I get an error of `Data is Null` then goes to the Exception.

I tried adding the migration and creates it successfully but when I command the `update-database`, it tells me that the Resources table is already existing which is actually right because this table has been created before I created the `DbSet<AssetResource>`.

Here's the whole code of getting the list:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<AssetSource>> GetAssetResources()
        {
            var lAssetSource = new List<AssetSource>();
            try
            {
                var sw = new Stopwatch();
                if (cache.TryGetValue(CACHE_KEYASSETSOURCE, out List<AssetSource> refListAssetSource))
                {
                    helper.LogMessage("Assets Sources are found in cache", LoggerModel.LoggingType.Information);
                    lAssetSource = refListAssetSource;
                }
                else
                {
                    var l = await context.AssetSources.ToListAsync();
                }
                return lAssetSource;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                helper.LogMessage(e.Message, Shared.Models.LoggerModel.LoggingType.Error);
                throw new NoObjectDetectedException(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Data is null` means that entity framework tries to bind nullable db column to non nullable property. Make sure that if the db column is for example `int, null` that the entity model in c# is `int?` and not `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Manually delete the table and then run the `update-database` command and you should be good. If you delete the table there will be no data in the table when running the `update-database` command. A good idea would be to rename the existing table before running the command, so you still have the existing data in the renamed table.